# Is there a simple consumer task example with samza and Kafka?

Tags: apache-samza

I am very new to Kafka and Samza. I tried the hello-samza exampe and it is working. What I am looking for is to create a samza task that reads the message from a kafka topic.The task I added does not throw any error, and is not reading any message from the topic. Yarn UI shows task as accepted.Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the Class

```
            public class MyTask implements StreamTask {

                @Override
                public void process(IncomingMessageEnvelope incomingMessageEnvelope, MessageCollector messageCollector, TaskCoordinator taskCoordinator) throws Exception {

                    System.out.println(" key - " + incomingMessageEnvelope.getKey()  + " | message " + incomingMessageEnvelope.getMessage());

                }


            }
```

Here is the properties file

```
            # Job
            job.factory.class=org.apache.samza.job.yarn.YarnJobFactory
            job.name=addresses

            # YARN
            yarn.package.path=file://${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${pom.version}-dist.tar.gz

            # Task
            task.class=samza.examples.wikipedia.task.MyTask
            task.inputs=addressestopic

            # Serializers
            serializers.registry.json.class=org.apache.samza.serializers.JsonSerdeFactory

            # Kafka System
            systems.kafka.samza.factory=org.apache.samza.system.kafka.KafkaSystemFactory
            systems.kafka.samza.msg.serde=json
            systems.kafka.consumer.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181/
            systems.kafka.producer.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

            # Job Coordinator
            job.coordinator.system=kafka
            # Add configuration to disable checkpointing for this job once it is available in the Coordinator Stream model
            # See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SAMZA-465?focusedCommentId=14533346&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14533346 for more details
            job.coordinator.replication.factor=1
```

Answer (score 3):

If the Yarn UI shows that your job is in "ACCEPTED" state and not "RUNNING", then it is possible that Yarn has not yet found resources to run your Samza job.

Usually, I have noticed this to happen when you *run out of disk space on your local box* on which you are executing.

- Can you check the Yarn UI (localhost:8088) and verify that "Active Nodes" (on the top) == 1 ?
- Additionally, you can cross-check the number of "Lost Nodes" to be equal to zero.
  If there are Lost Nodes, you can click on the link to see why it is not available for use.